# Hack into a Lottery

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

You've recently made an account on a dodgy gambling site, where for a fee of 25 dollars, they will pay you back a random amount between 0 and 50 dollars. After getting around 5 dollars twice, you decide to prove the site is a scam. After accessing their external firewall with the default password, you find your way onto their database server, and find where the values for the minimum and maximum amounts are held. You decide to plug 25 '9's in as the maximum value, but get an error message saying the maximum value must be of type 'uint64'. However it is now that you notice some number keys don't seem to type into the remote console correctly. The challenge appears before you almost as if typed up on a Q+A site.

using only the conveniently installed programs for testing and executing your particular language, output the maximum size of an unsigned 64-bit integer value, however almost everything except the programming tools are broken on this machine, leaving you without the use of the numbers 1,2,4,6,8 - in either source code or literals, you also notice that it seems to take an exponentially longer amount of time to execute the program for each additional piece of code, so you'd better keep it short if you want to get rich before the drawing!

---

## The Challenge

- Write a program which outputs 18446744073709551615, the maximum value of an unsigned 64-bit integer, as either a number, or a single string.
- Your source code cannot contain any of the characters '1','2','4','6' or '8'
- if your language does not have an unsigned 64-bit integer or equivalent, the output can be in string format or otherwise, but must be the above number.
- this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in each language wins!

Comment: predefined values. pfft

Comment: can output be a hexadecimal number?

Comment: @user902383 must be in the exact format, feel free to parse it as a hex number, as long as the output is in normal decimal notation.

Comment: You don't need any constants, e.g. `int x, y, z; y = x - x; z = factorial(y);` at which point `y == 0` and `z == 1` from `z` you can get any number, including the real numbers. I've considered designing a language without digits: e.g. `ONE = |{}|!` (factorial of cardinality of empty set), then `TWO = ONE + ONE`, and so on.

Comment: What an odd challenge

Comment: I love the story lol. More challenges need a backstory like this

Comment: So now that there are many solutions to choose from, was the gambling site a fraud?

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## [Beeswax](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl), 3 bytes

```
_M{
```

Explanation:

```
_   # Create a bee going horizontally across the line, reading the code
 M  # Decrement the bee's counter, which starts at 0.
    # This will set the counter to 2^64-1, because as bees don't have a concept of
    # negative numbers, all values that are negative are translated to 2^64-n,
    # and in this case, n = -1, as we are calculating 0 - 1.
  { # Print the value
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/beeswax#@x/vW/3/PwA)

This language is *perfect* for this challenge.

Here is an extract from the [Esolang page on Beeswax](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beeswax):

> As everyone knows, bees don’t have a concept of negative numbers, but they discovered that they can use the most significant bit of an address to get around that. Thus, coordinates relative to a bee’s position are realized by the [two’s complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of the coordinates. This way, half of the 64-bit address space is available for local addressing without wraparound in each direction.
>
> The maximum positive 64-bit two’s complement address is 9223372036854775807 or 0x7fffffffffffffff in 64 bit hex. All values from 0 up to this value translate identically to the same 64 bit value. All values n in the opposite (negative) direction translate to 2^64-n. For example: n=-1 is addressed by 18446744073709551615. n=-9223372036854775808 is addressed by 9223372036854775808.

This is basically unsigned longs.

EDIT: I'm still expecting Dennis to outgolf me with a 2-byte solution.

Comment: You don't need to print it if the form will return the value. See other answers.

Comment: There are two solutions with the same length. The other one is  _!{

Answer (score 44):

## C, 26 bytes

```
main(){printf("%lu",~0l);}
```

Prints a `unsigned long` value.

Requires the size of `long` to be 64 bits.

Comment: Nice one. Pretty much the same in Perl: `print~0`.

Comment: `~0l` should work.

Comment: Source code cannot contain the character '1'.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin it's a lowercase 'L' :)

Comment: @Quentin ^^ Ah! Sorry! Didn't notice (was using mobile, "l" and "1" looked the same). This post has my upvote now.

Comment: You're assuming `sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT == 64`.  A reasonable assumption for golf, but worth pointing out.

Comment: Why does this work? What is the behaviour of '~' followed by an integer?

Comment: @Chris it's the bitwise not operator.

Answer (score 35):

### 64-bit SBCL Common Lisp, 18 bytes

`most-positive-word`

Most positive word on 64-bit compiler is 64uint. It's something.

Comment: Best syntax :))

Comment: Makes me very happy

Answer (score 31):

### CJam (4 bytes)

```
GG#(
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=GG%23()

This calculates 16<sup>16</sup> - 1 using builtin `G` for 16 and the decrement operator `(`.

Comment: Definitely GG! ;)

Comment: gg, Peter, gg..

Answer (score 25):

## Python3 REPL, 12 bytes

In REPL: `~-(~-3<<9*7)`

Outside of REPL: `print~-(~-3<<9*7)` <--> Python2!

Here's another one at 17 bytes: `~-(~-3<<ord("?"))`.

### Explanation

Nothing super fancy. Here's it broken down:

```
~-           | Subtract 1 from the next value.
  (          | 
   ~-3       | Subtract 1 from 3, resulting in 2
      <<     | Binary shift 2's digits to left,
        9*7  | by 9*7 (63).
           ) | The value inside the parentheses is now 2**64.
```

The resulting expression is roughly (but not quite)  `~-(2<<63)` -> `(2**64)-1`. I use the [tadpole operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150525-00/?p=45044) twice here. A golfing tip about it is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37553/41754).

There is also `sys.maxint` in Python2 which can be used, but I won't be looking at that.

[repl.it](https://repl.it/Fr7H/0) <- testing link.

Comment: Why does this code look like a cat that ate another cat?

Answer (score 16):

## bc, <del>15</del> 13 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to manatwork.*

```
(a=9+7)^a-3/3
```

Nothing fancy, just (16^16)-1.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: `(a=9+7)^a-3/3`

Comment: Thanks I was originally doing something like that in bash before I realised my answer was better as pure bc.

Answer (score 14):

### [dc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)), 7 bytes

I think it's allowed for stack based languages to leave the answer on the top cell of the stack, similar to a return value for functions. If explicit printing is needed, add `p` at the end of the code.

```dc
AZ5E^z-
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@@8YZeoaV6Vb8P8/AA)

It computes (2 <sup>64</sup> - 1) using several tricks:

- `2` is given as the number of digits (`Z`) found in integer 10 (`A`)
- `64` is given as `5E`. By default dc uses 10 as the input radix. Even so, it can accept numbers in hexadecimal notation, but they will be converted differently than you'd expect. Example:
  (5E)<sub>default</sub> = (5E)<sub>(input radix = 10)</sub> = (5 * 10 <sup>1</sup>) + (14<sub>(E)</sub> * 10 <sup>0</sup>) = 50 + 14 = 64
- `1` is given as the stack's depth (`z`), since only (2 <sup>64</sup>) was present then

#### Alternative story:

> However it is now that you notice some number keys don't seem to type
>   into the remote console correctly. You take a deep breath and start
>   testing each numerical key. It is worse than you thought! Not a single
>   one works, and you're left with the task to produce your desired
>   integer by using only letters and symbols.

**Solution in dc:** computing (16 <sup>16</sup> - 1), still 7 bytes!

```
Fz+d^z-          # push 15, push 1, add, duplicate, exponentiate, push 1, subtract
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@@9WpZ0SV6Vb8P8/AA)

Comment: Great alternative story

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
žJn<
```

Explanation:

```
žJ   # Push 4294967296
  n  # Squared
   < # Decreased by one
```

Finally! A chance to use `05AB1E`'s builtins for powers of two!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390n1eezf//AA)

Another 4 byte answer:

```
žxo<
```

Explanation:

```
  o  # 2 to the power of
žx   # 64
   < # Decreased by one
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X0W@zf//AA)

(if anyone is wondering, this question is older than all the other 4-byte answers)

Comment: I feel like there's a shorter solution along the lines of `64o<` but I haven't found it yet. Something like `'@Ço<` with a creative 64 push... If you manage to push 64 with 1 byte, you can get 3 is the point I'm trying to make.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
⁴*`’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocYtWwqOGmf//AwA)

**Explanation**

```
⁴     # 16
 *    # exponentiate
  `   # last link as a monad, repeating the argument
   ’  # decrement
```

Answer (score 11):

## MATLAB / Octave, 5 bytes

@Sanchises posted an excellent MATLAB answer, however this one is a considerably different approach, so I'll post it anyway:

```
tic/0
```

In MATLAB, `tic` returns the number of milliseconds past since the program was opened. Crucially the value it returns is a `uint64` type. This gets away from having to cast a number to `uint64` from MATLABs default type of `double`.

Any number divided by 0 in MATLAB is considered as infinity which for non-floating point types, MATLAB represents this as the maximum integer value for that type.

---

This also works with **Octave** though depending on which interpreter you use it may spit out a "division by zero" warning as well. You can try the code [online here](http://octave-online.net/) though as I say you get a /0 warning that doesn't appear in MATLAB.

Comment: Really clever approach, nice one.

Comment: I'm only seeing this answer now. Very clever! (of course, it does not work if you execute this on a very fast computer such that `tic==0` at startup )

Answer (score 10):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 28 bytes

```java
v->Long.toUnsignedString(~0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw9D4IwEIZ3fsWNNJHGHWV00onoYhwqH02xXBt6JSEG/3qtgNPde8/zXidGkXX1K6jemoGgi5l7Upq3HitSBvlpW/LE@qdWFVRaOAcXoRDeCcB2dSQojtGoGvrI0pIGhfL@ADFIxxYV4P/scIveblUKaOEIYcyKs0HJyVzRKYlNveL0s2chX9rl5KjpufHEbUSkMW25sFZPKXqtGftpczKHLw)

Comment: Missing java "boilerplate" and system.out.print part

Comment: @ViktorMellgren This declares a lambda expression, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: This requires Java 8

Comment: Yes java 8 and up, no more boilerplate! Fear codegolfers! Java is a real contester now. This is the time you all were so scared about, all your codegolfing language are for nothing! Oh wait still 30 bytes,... *hides*

Comment: Why not just ()->~0L? The question allowed numeric output

Comment: @k_g in Java, `long`s are always signed, they're only _treated as_ unsigned by certain static methods in the `Long` class. Returning `~0L` numerically would be the smallest signed value, not the largest unsigned value (though they have the same representation).

Comment: @mbomb007 Java 8 is the latest supported version. When you mean Java now, it's Java 8 by default. Java 7 isn't supported anymore for wide audience. I'll keep naming my Java answers "Java".

Comment: I could have written `()->"18446744073709551615"` for 26 bytes, but that's the boring answer and no one would have learned of the hidden Java 8's "unsigned" methods.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Same with Python 3, but if someone just puts "Python", it means it works in both 2 and 3. Since we have answers all over the site that use "Java" to mean "Java 7", it's better to include the version.

Comment: Python 2.7 is still supported, that's a big difference here.

Comment: Surely the "shorter solution" uses the illegal characters `1846`.

Comment: Oh... didn't think about those restrictions. Gonna delete it.

Comment: `Long.MAX_VALUE​/0.5`

Comment: @carusocomputing the value is then rounded: `1.8446744073709552E19` instead of `18446744073709551615`.

Answer (score 7):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), <del>18</del>, 16 bytes

- Saved 2 bytes, thx @MrScapegrace

```js
(9-7)^(55+9)-3/3
```

Comment: can you use something like `-3/3` to get `-1`?

Comment: @MrScapegrace, yep that's a nice idea, thank you !

Comment: @boboquack 55+9 = 64, not 63!

Answer (score 7):

#### PHP, 16 bytes

This is much like the answer from Ven: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110751/38505

```
printf("%u",~0);
```

https://repl.it/Frcy/0

> For this to work, you need to be in a 64-bit architecture. This is because ~0 is -1, which is 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111‌​1111 in binary, in 64 bits, compared to 11111111111111111111111111111111 in 32-bits, and the numbers are plataform-dependent - [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel)

Comment: Lol. This works in `bash` too: `printf %u $[~0]`.

Comment: Aha, nice @manatwork

Comment: This is architecture-dependent, it doesn't work on i386.

Comment: @pts Obviously! i386 is 16/32-bits. PHP is very picky about that. For this to work, you need to be in a 64-bit architecture. This is because `~0` is `-1`, which is `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` in binary, in 64 bits, compared to `11111111111111111111111111111111` in 32-bits, and the numbers are plataform-dependent.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑYou're welcome. I must admit that I slacked a bit. I've copy-pasted 32 1's. If you want, you can fix your grammar a bit on your answer.

Answer (score 6):

### MATLAB / Octave, 22 bytes

```
eye(['~rw}?='-9 ''])/0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@59amaoRrV5XVF5rb6uua6mgrh6rqW/w/z8A)

`eye` is used to create a unit matrix (matrix with `1`  on the diagonal, zero otherwise). Without arguments, this creates a `1x1` unit matrix, or in other words, just a `1`. It takes an optional argument, which is the data type ('class' in MATLAB terminology) of the created matrix. We thus ask for a `1` of class `uint64` , and divide it by zero which results in `Inf` in MATLAB, which gets clipped at `intmax('uint64')`.

The vector `['~rw}?='-9 '']` evaluates to `'uint64'`. Concatenating an empty char to a vector is 1 byte shorter than using `char('~rw}?='-9)`.

Reasoning towards this answer: the built-in `intmax` sadly evaluates to the maximum of a 32 bit signed integer. The obvious next option is `uint64()`, which contains the forbidden characters. The alternative is to use a function that takes a string as a data type. Obvious candidates are `intmax` and `cast`, but alternatives include `zeros`, `ones` and `eye`.

```
eye(['~rw}?='-9 ''])/0    % Winning version! 22 bytes.
intmax(['~rw}?='-9 ''])   % Obvious candidate. 23 bytes.
1/zeros(['~rw}?='-9 ''])  % 24 bytes
cast(Inf,['~rw}?='-9 '']) % 25 bytes. Also an obvious candidate, but actually very long.
```

<sup>Note: MATLAB is installed by default on virtually all dodgy gambling sites.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>29</s> 14 bytes

```powershell
0xC000PB/3-3/3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@29Q4WxgYBDgpG@sa6xv/P8/AA)

*Thanks to @n0rd for essentially golfing this in half.*

This leverages the inbuilt unary `PB` operator that basically functions as "multiply the preceding number by `1125899906842624`" (i.e., how many bytes are in a pebibyte). That's coupled with the hex `0xC000`, or `49152`, so `49152 pebibytes`. We divide that by `3`, yielding `18446744073709551616`, and subtract `3/3` to get the final value.

Comment: `"0x$(7-3)000PB-9/9"|iex`

Comment: `0xC000PB/3-3/3`

Comment: @n0rd Oh, that's dang clever, using `PB` like that. Thanks!

Comment: @n0rd pretty impressive, welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
alert(0xafebff0+'737095'+0xc99f)
```

Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: Remove alert as this can be run in a console.

Answer (score 5):

## BF, 108 bytes

```
-[----->+<]>--.+++++++.----..++.+.---..----.+++++++.----.++++.-------.+++++++++.----..----.+++++.-----.++++.
```

If each command is considered as 3 bits, this is potentially 41 bytes.

Comment: Each command is one byte. Not 3 bits.

Comment: Well yes, that's why I put it as 108 bytes...

Comment: Yeah, but you said "this is potentially 41 bytes", which it's not.

Comment: An interpreter could be made to interpret 3-bit groups as one of eight commands `+-<>[].,`

Comment: That already exists. It's called http://esolangs.org/wiki/Binaryfuck

Comment: Yes, but, the problem is still that the interpreter takes each value as 1 byte instead of 1 bit.

Comment: That's basically what Golunar is for. Sesos is similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54008/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-timtech).

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Kritixi Lithos*

```
bieegheeahdhajffbgbf
T`l`d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8@VlJmamp6RmpqYkZKRmJWWlpSelMYVkpCTkPL/PwA)

**Explanation**

```
bieegheeahdhajffbgbf
```

Replaces the non-existent/empty input with this string. This particular string was generated by the "inverse" of this program. It encodes `a` through `j` as `0` through `9`, respectively.

```
T`l`d
```

This is a `T`ransliteration stage. The `l` and `d` are character sets used for transliteration. `l` represents the lowercase alphabet, `d` is all digits. So, it maps `abcdefghij` back to `0123456789`.

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8/l5Onq6u7h6uro4eLh6OXm5uTu5MYVkuCTkPL/PwA is 1 byte shorter (I used `d` instead of `EO`)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Oh yeah. I'm still not fully awake :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>64, 62, 58</s>, 54 bytes

```
(((((()()()()){}){}){}){}){({}<(({}()){}[()])>[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMMNCFQs7oWCWlU19poAAmweLSGZqymHZisra79/x8A)

[Try it online!]

*Four bytes saved thanks to @Riley!*

Explanation:

```
#Push a 64
(((((()()()()){}){}){}){})

#While true
{

  #Pop the top of the stack. We'll store this value for later, but first
  ({}

  #Before pushing the value
  <

    #Push (N + 1) * 2 - 1
    # (where N is the number underneath, originally 0)
    (({}()){}[()])

  >

  #And push the TOS minus one back on
  [()])

#endwhile
}

#Pop the zero left over
{}

#And decrement the number underneath
({}[()])
```

For the record, I tried pushing 32 and quadrupling, but it's the same byte count.

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using one of the `()`s from 64 to push the 1: [`((((((())()()()){}){}){}){})`](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BAZqaGmCoWV2LQP//AwA)

Comment: @Riley Aha, of course! Thanks

Comment: 56 bytes: [`((((((())()()()){}){}){}){}[()]){({}<(({}){}())>[()])}{}`](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BAZqaGmCoWV0LR9EamrGa1RrVtTYaGmABoLQdWLC2uvb/fwA)

Comment: 54 bytes:[`((((((<>)()()()()){}){}){}){}){({}<(({}){}())>[()])}{}`](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BBjZ2mhpQqFldi4Q0qmttNDTAHKCUXbSGZqxmbXXt//8A)

Comment: Um, can't you just do [`N*2+1`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMMNCFQs7oWCWlU19poaIA5QCm7aA3NWM3a6tr//wE) instead of `(N+1)*2-1`?

Answer (score 5):

### Python3 REPL, 11 bytes

```
~0^~0>>~077
```

#### How it works

- ~0 is -1 (two's complement, an infinite sequence of '1's)
- 077 is 63 in octal, so ~077 is -64
- Shift right with negative parameter is a shift to the left
- Putting all together, -1 xor (-1 << 64) is the number we are looking for

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```js
[...'䠎ᴐIF╏ɧ'].map(s=>s.charCodeAt()).join``
```

Comment: You can change the characters to `'䠎ᴐIF╏ɧ'` and remove the `-27`

Comment: @jdp Nice one, thanks :)

Comment: `'䠎ᴐIF╏ɧ'.replace(/./g,s=>s.charCodeAt())` seems to save 3 bytes; note that this appears to be a snippet rather than a function or program, but you could prefix `_=>` to turn it into a function.

Answer (score 5):

## C++, 46 bytes.

```
int m(){std::cout<<unsigned long long(5+3-9);}
```

First time ever doing a code golf, but I'm fairly happy with myself. Will happily take any critique/suggestions :)

Answer (score 4):

## C# 6, 31 bytes

```
()=>System.Console.Write(~0UL);
```

Pretty much the same as Java.

## C# 5, 56 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(~0UL);}}
```

Comment: The C# 6 answer is only an anonymous action, which are also present in C# 5.

Comment: Also the challenge only asks you to output the number so you could compile to a `Func<ulong>` as: `()=>~0UL;`

Comment: It also doesn't say that you can't use any input so you could compile to a `Func<int, ulong>` to save a byte: `_=>~0UL;` and I think it would still be valid.

Answer (score 4):

## Forth (gforth), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
true U.
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@19SVJqqEKr3/z8A)

`true` is the same as `-1`. `U.` prints a number as an unsigned integer.

This works on TIO, possibly because it has a 64-bit architecture? I'm not sure. If I run `-1 U.` on repl.it, for example, I get 2**32-1. If repl.it supported double-length integers, outputting them would use `UD.` instead.

Comment: You can probably reduce this to `-3 3 / U.`

Comment: Or, even better: `true U.`  (which also rhythms nicely)

Comment: Oh, I forget about `true`, because I'm so used to using `0` and `1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 58 bytes

R has only 32-bit integers, and with 64-bit doubles, the number 18446744073709551615 [is not accurately represented](https://tio.run/nexus/r#FctNCoAgEEDhfacYaFM7JX9y4WHEJhoIR3A2nt5s@eB7XIW4tK1lqlhiCGGHFRoKyINwUatv6iAMhWEaLEI35VmS/nH0qE9jnDdG@cOrYK122i59jA8), hence this will return a string. I can't even use 64-bit integer packages, because many of them have `64` in the names. Probably not the right tool for the job.

```
x=as.character((9+7)^(9+7))
n=nchar(x)
substr(x,n,n)='5';x
```

computes `16^16` and replaces the last character with a `5`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@19hm1isl5yRWJSYXJJapKFhqW2uGQcmNbnybPNAMhoVmlzFpUnFJUCWTp5Onqatuqm6dcX//wA)

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 8 bytes

```
l_5Z%EZD
```

This could probably be improved, but I'm not familiar with strings and types in MATL just yet.

[Try it at matl.io](https://matl.io/?code=l_5Z%25EZD&version=19.8.0)

Explanation:

```
l       % push 1
_       % unary minus
5       % push 5, corresponds to type 'uint64'
Z%      % convert 1 to this type
E       % double
ZD      % display as a string
```

Comment: It'd need to be YY5Z%ZD to force uint64 type, but I don't know why using 1 5Z% instead just works...

Comment: You can't use 8.

Comment: @xnor Oops, fixed.

Comment: Can you add a demo link using either https://matl.suever.net or http://matl.tryitonline.net?

Comment: @Suever Sure, it's there now.

Comment: @Sanchises It's a Matlab thing: `typecast(inf,'uint64')` doesn't give `18446744073709551615` either. Not sure why. `typecast` depends on the internal data representation, so I guess anything can happen

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah, of course - I thought `cast` was used, but it makes sense if `typecast` is used. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>223</s> 193 bytes

Includes +1 for `-A`
-30 thanks to DJMcMayhem

```
((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()){}){}()){}){}())[()()()()])[][]())[[]()()])[]))()()()())[[]()()])[][()])[()()()()])()()()())[(()()()){}()])()()()()))()()())[()])[()()]))()()()())[(()()()){}()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@BC2iCoGZ1LRAh0dEQcQ3NWM3o2OhYkAiIhPA1NWGyyKLRYAqhD6EGYQmKOEIephHFZFRd////13UEAA)

This just pushed the ASCII values of and prints as characters.

For reference, it takes 338 bytes to generate the actual number using the [Integer meta golfer](https://brain-flak.github.io/integer/).

```
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()){}()){}){}()){}()){({}[()])}{}()){}()){}())){}{})){}{})()){}{})){}{})){}{})()){}{})){}{})){}{}){}){}())){}{}){}())()){}{})){}{}){}){}){}())()){}{})()){}{})){}{}){}())){}{})()){}{})){}{})){}{})){}{})()){}{})()){}{})){}{}){}())){}{}){}){}())()){}{})()){}{})){}{})
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69BHaAJgprVtWACRoMIjeraaA3NWM1aJDEQASSBCiGkBgoPtxjMZBgPyNTAVIAqga4Arh2bBagyOLXit@P/fwA)

Comment: You could save a bunch if you take advantage of the stack-height nilad `[]`. For example: [`((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()){}){}()){}){}())[()()()()])[][]())[[]()()])[]))()()()())[[]()()])[][()])[()()()()])()()()())[(()()()){}()])()()()()))()()())[()])[()()]))()()()())[(()()()){}()])`](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@BC2iCoGZ1LRAh0dEQcQ3NWM3o2OhYkAiIhPA1NWGyyKLRYAqhD6EGYQmKOEIephHFZFRd////13UEAA) (Possibly more I'm missing)

Comment: Also, I think you can add one byte for `-A` since standard invocation already includes `-f`, so it's only one off to do `-fA` instead

Comment: @DJMcMayhem When did we start using +1 for the arguments? I didn't think about `[]` I'll look at that when I get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Swift, 8 bytes

```
UInt.max
```

#### outside playground / repl - 15 bytes

```
print(UInt.max)
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 10 bytes

```
9+7
Ans^Ans-0!
```

Comment: TI-BASIC can't calculate, store or display this number exactly—floats only have 14 digits (about 44 bits) of precision.

Answer (score 3):

## x64 Assembly, 7 bytes

hex (assembled): 4831C048FFC8C3

disassembled, commented:

    `XOR RAX,RAX    ;Zero the value of 64 bit register RAX
    DEC RAX        ;Decrement the value of RAX
    RET            ;Return this value`

RAX is a 64 bit register, and is most often used to return integer arguments (eg, C). By decrementing 1, its value rolls over from 0 to... 2^64-1, which is exactly needed.
Though, the assembled binary contains ones and fours and eights, the assembly doesn't, but the assembled file is counted in assembly, so does it count? Ow, my head.
Also, output is return value in this case.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <strike>50 bytes</strike> 47 bytes

```
parseInt(5%3+"7nq9nb9r7b",33+7-9)+btoa("×­y")
```

Comment: Why do you append the answer to `''`?

Comment: @Marie it doesn't: https://repl.it/repls/SubstantialNoisyRectangle

Comment: You misunderstood. Why does your code start with `''+`? Unless I am missing something, which is possible, you dont need that.

Comment: ah, ok. I didn't read the requirements right. It can be "either a number, or a single string". Thank you

Comment: Lol, I didnt notice that but my actual point was that btoa returns a string so either way the result should be a string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
C*h7"ÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=C%2ah7%22%C3%BF&debug=0)

### How it works

```
C*h7"ÿ
    "ÿ   creates the string "ÿ" (U+00FF)
  h7     creates 8 (7+1)
 *       generates "ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ"
C        convert to integer from base 256
```

This works because `18446744073709551615 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 3 bytes

Port of the 05AB1E answer. But 1 byte shorter.

```
♦ó(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzGWHN2v8/w8A)

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, <strike>16</strike> <strike>14</strike> <strike>12</strike> <strike>9</strike> 7 bytes

```
9(.+.?(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31JDT1vPXuP/fwA)

```
9(.+.?(
     9( = 8
     .+ = +8 = 16
     .? = ^16 = 16^16
     (  = -1
```

Some alternative solutions (also 7B)

```
5(33(?(
7).+.?(
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
3’*“@‘’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/8qGGm1qOGOQ6PGmYAmf//AwA)

Comment: Why does the TIO link have different code?

Comment: @Okx Forgot to update the link, fixed :)

Comment: I think you could do `3’` to get 2.

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks :P.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
int(e
Ans^Ans²³-1
```

- Many commands in TI-Basic are single or two-byte tokens.
- The superscript characters are different tokens, so they are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript 55 bytes

```
alert(""+(590300>>5)+(59530-3>>3)+7370955+(3*59*73>>3))
```

the code generates and then alerts the string 18446744073709551615 using bitwise operations

590300>>5 18446
59530-3>>3 7440
7370955
3*59*73>>3 1615

Comment: Displays `2588673709551615` for me...

Comment: `alert(0xafebff0+'7370955'+(3*59*73>>3))` works fine

Comment: I am leaving it as it is for the sake of keeping the method used instead of just copying someone else now.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 20 bytes

```
()=>ulong.MaxValue;
```

Comment: This is neither a full program nor a function / lambda and therefore invalid.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! As Corvus_192 pointed out, this isn't a full program or function, so it is invalid. If you *output* this value somehow, the answer will be valid. (For example, print to the console, return from a function, etc.) I'm going to vote to delete this answer for now, but if you [edit] your answer to be valid, I will retract my vote, or vote to undelete it. You could also [flag] it for a moderator to undelete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
p~0^~0>>~077
```

Prints out the number. In REPL mode this would be 11 bytes (without the 'p')

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica <strike>44</strike> 39 Bytes, No numbers

Well I could do the 22 Byte answer `Print[(9+7)^(9+7)-3^0]`

Here's an answer using addition to build up to the desired number with no numbers in the code:

```
f=Nest[#+#&,p=E/E,#]&;f@f@(f@p+f@f@p)-p
```

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Martin-Ender

Comment: `p=E/E` and `f@f[f@p+f@f@p]`

Comment: Actually, it's shorter to define an operator `±` instead of a function `f` and you can delay assigning `p` until the `Nest` is being called: `±x_:=Nest[#+#&,p=E/E,x];±±(±p+±±p)-p`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Incorporating the first two. The ± character eats up 2 bytes, so no savings by that measure, but it costs 3 extra bytes to define.

Comment: `±` is a single byte in several single-byte code pages e.g. the Windows ANSI code page CP1252, which is actually the default encoding for source files on Windows installations.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
t^Jyh7J
```

[Online interpreter link.](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=J%2B9+7t%5EJJ)

[Uses Emigna's algorithm.](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110765/41024)

*Thanks to [Leaky Nun](/u/48934) for digging this answer out so that I could -1 it.*
*-1 because I found `yh7` which is shorter than `+9 7`.*

`yh7` seems to be the shortest way we can make `16` without using `12468`.

Comment: I'm sure you know what you can golf down now.

Comment: @LeakyNun The thing is that I can't use `12468`, although this is an answer from when I was inexperienced. Let's see what we've got here...

Comment: It's the same as the previous answer from you wherein I commented.

Comment: @LeakyNun I found something else too. Golfed.

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 16 bytes

26 bytes: My first submit

```
main(){std::cout<<(~0UL);}
```

[EDIT]24 bytes: () is not necessary

```
main(){std::cout<<~0UL;}
```

[EDIT]16 bytes: without main(){}

```
std::cout<<~0UL;
```

Obviously, Every c++ program must have an entry point function.

So I think we should not count it as a part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, and i'm sorry for violate the rules. i'm totally new to this site xD

Comment: no worries - the site has a couple of things you'll need to get used to, but it's definitely a great way to waste time and have some fun, check out the [questions guide](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and if you have any questions just make a post in the [meta forums](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/) - best of luck.

Comment: @ConnorLSW this is not the case, we go as far as [allowing answers with exactly the same content as each other](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10812/32686) (currently at +24/-7). We absolutely encourage users to post answers in the same language as already posted in.

Answer (score 2):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 67 bytes + 3 bytes = <del>162</del> 70 bytes

(+3 is for flag `-w`)

```
*Z~vZZZZvZvvZZZZvZZ-vZZvZZ-ZZvZZt
e*fad`c'`bac^^zba^^bc da^^cabca^c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@68VVVcWBQRlUWVQOkq3DEKByRKuVK20xJSEZPWEpMTkuLiqpMS4uKRkhRQglZyYlJwYl/z//3/dcgA)

Chip is a 2D language inspired by integrated circuits, input and output are broken down into individual bits which travel through gates and across wires.

Let's look at the ungolfed version:

```
*Z~-v-Z-Z-Z-Zv-Zvv-Z-Z-Z-Zvv-Zv-Zvv-Z-Zv-Zv-Zv-Z-Zv-Z-Zvt
e*f a d c c bc abc c c   abc ab abc   ad ac ac a bc a ac
```

The first portion has two components: `*Z~` and `e*f`. `*Z~` creates a 1-cycle pulse to kick off the circuit. `e*f` is equivalent to the value `0x30`, which is the ASCII code for "0".

The remainder of the circuit has one portion for each ASCII digit of the output. For example:

```
-Zv-
 bc
```

The elements `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are the low four bits of output: `a` is `0x01`, `b` is `0x02`, and so on. In this sample, we have `b` and `c`, giving us `0x02 | 0x04 = 0x06`. This combines with the code above to give us `0x30 | 0x06 = 0x36`, which is the ASCII code for "6".

The `Z`s with nothing below them simply result in "0".

At the end, `t` causes the program to halt.

---

If instead you want the actual binary value instead, corresponding to eight `0xFF` bytes, you can accomplish this in only **22 + 3 = 25 bytes**:

```
a*ZZZZZZZt
dc
*eh
fg*b
```

The output of this can be verified by e.g. piping it into `od -vtu8`.

Comment: This is answer 111111

Comment: @wat Oooo so it is :)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 39 bytes

```
{$0=(a+=++a)^(a*=a*=a*a);sub(".$",5)}5
```

Usage:

```
awk '{$0=(a+=++a)^(a*=a*=a*a);sub(".$",5)}5' <<< " "
```

Annoyingly `AWK` has trouble with integer math beyond `2^53` since it internally converts large integers to 64-bit doubles.  Since `2^64` can be exactly represented as a double, its string representation should be exactly `18446744073709551616` (it is on my machine, anyway). Unfortunately, `2^64 - 1 == 2^64`, so I could not simply decrement the value, hence the workaround via string substitution.

Byte-count includes 1 additional byte due to requiring at least 1 byte for input which could be `ctrl-D`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/WsXAViNR21ZbO1EzTiNRyxaMEjWti0uTNJT0VJR0TDVrDf//VwAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
I3Z%WZD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39M4SjU8yuX/fwA)

Do a `typecast` on 3 (actual number doesn't matter much) to `uint64`, which reinterprets the bits of the default double precision float as an unsigned integer, giving a large value. Raise that to the power of 2, overflowing the range of `uint64`, which makes Matlab clamp it to the upper limit of 18446744073709551615.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 99 bytes

```
-->>->+>->>>+>->+>>+>->>>+>+>>>+>+[>+++[-<+++++>]<[->+++<]<++]>>+>>->>+>+>++>->>->>->>>>->>>+>[+.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzRCYBADEMHCnGCkkVKP1QQRPBDuPnr9U4saaDhpduznvfR9iuTlCj01XDoPzDdBcBpqFGYswKLHkQBRReM0ZvS98KxWGS@)

Uses a ternary system for numbers between 0 and 8 (and a little cheat for the 9).

```
-, - = 0
-, 0 = 1
-, + = 2
0, - = 3
0, 0 = 4
0, + = 5
+, - = 6
+, 0 = 7
+, + = 8
+, ++ = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <del>67</del> <del>52</del> <del>47</del> <del>45</del> 39 bytes

```
b=9+7;(b**b+'').substr(0,b)+btoa('×­y')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üó|>b
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81a27c3e62&i=&a=1&m=2)

This is simply the packed version of the program `64|2v` which means `2**64-1`. Yes, boring.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>62</s> 58 bytes

```
(()())((()()()){}){({}<({({})({}[()])}{})>[()])}{}({}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU0NTUwNMARnVtZrVGtW1NhogUhOIozU0YzVrgWw7GAsm@P8/AA)

This runs into a timeout, but here's the "source".

```
(()())                 init stack with 2
((()()()){}){          repeat 6 times
    (
        {}
        <({({})({}[()])}{})> square the value
        [()]           decrement loop counter
    )
}
{}                     pop 0
({}[()])               decrement value
                       implicitly print it
```

It calculates ((((((2^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)-1 and prints it

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>26</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```c
f(){return~0UL;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P01Ds7ootaS0KK/OINTHuvZ/bmJmHlCsNK84Mz0vNUUhJz8vHUIk2gIVWxcUZeaVpGkoqebklCrpJGoCtQAA)

Saved 8 bytes from changing from printf to return. Saved 2 bytes by using
the bitwise NOT from the C++ answer.

Comment: Your returned type is signed int

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 21 bytes

```python
print~-(5-3)**(97-33)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM6@kTlfDVNdYU0tLw9Jc19hY8/9/AA)

`5-3` = 2, `97-33` = 64, `~-` to decrement.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 12 bytes (UTF-8)

```
#
(
*
*
*
Ā
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X5lLg0sLDI80/P8PAA)

I can't think of a cleverer way to fold this up that wouldn't kill the squaring. Note that `Ā` has codepoint 256. Two *characters* can be shaved off by using 65536 instead, but it comes out to precisely the same byte count:

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 12 bytes

```
#
(
*
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X5lLg0sLCD9MaGj4/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```julia
print(~UInt(0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69Eoy7UE0gaaGr@/w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 27 bytes

```bash
printf %u $[57#OSiLrEickbS]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1VEEl2tRc2T8406fINTM5Oyk49v9/AA)

Uses pre-calculated base-57 string. Why base-57? Because anything larger would require one of the prohibited digits.

```
printf %u $[-3/3]
```

would also work for 17 bytes, but that’s been done...

Comment: Or use `$[~0]` for **15 bytes**.

Comment: @GammaFunction, `printf %u $[~0]` is giving me a "syntax error: operand expected" on my bash.

Comment: Ah, it must be a Bash 5 thing. My mistake, that would make it non-competing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```
echo high uint
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhbrUpMz8hUyMtMzFEoz80ogglA5mBoA)

Answer (score 1):

## MSSQL, <s>33</s> <s>37</s> <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
SELECT power(9.+7,9+7)-77*5
```

Bigint is too big, so I'm counting 2^64-1 manually. I'm not sure why, but power(2,64) gives 18446744073709552000, so I have to substract 385.

*-2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

Comment: Source code can't contain 2.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff fixed.

Comment: `power(2,64)` is probably converted from floating-point, and the conversion routines are probably limited by the 17-digit known precision of floating-point values i.e. they can't assume you want exactly 2^64, so they just give you a value which converts to the same floating-point value.

Comment: @ETHproductions yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 bytes

```
GpG s r#È*A+PG+Fs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@9e4K5QrFCkfLhDy1E7wF3brfj/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 41 bytes:

```
:im a <C-o><C-v><C-a>
i0a7a3a3a5a73a3a073709550a5a0a5
```

This uses the `<C-a>` command (increment) to get around the restriction of not using 1, 2, 4, 6, or 8. No TIO link since this doesn't seem to work in V, but it definitely works on vim locally.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cardinal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal) 42 bytes

```
%+.+=tt.''..*."7"'.."07370955"0+.*t.0+.**.
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#@6@qradtW1Kip66up6elp2SuBKSVDMyNzQ0sTU2VDLT1tEr0QKSW3v//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 31 bytes

```
fn main(){print!("{}",!0usize)}
```

This isn't portable code (assumes a 64-bit architecture), but I can't use the `u64` type due to its name containing forbidden characters.

Comment: I think you can remove the space after the comma.

Comment: Oh, beginner mistake! Thanks, updated :)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 10 bytes

```
<:JSB^<:5x
```

`JSB` is a constant equal to `65536`. `<:` is `x - 1`. `5x` is 5 as an extended integer. `^` is exponentiation.

I spent a really long time working on this. Here are my other solutions:

```
<:JSB^<:5x
<:^~+:>:7x
<:^~*:<:5x
<:^~*:>:3x
<:^~+:<:9x
<:^~x:JCMPX
<:x:*:*:JSB
<:^~x:%:#a.
#.1x#~*:<:9
<:x:^~>.^^^0
<:x:^~>.^^*_
<:^~<:p:>:5x
<:^~-:x:JBOXED
<:x:^~>.^~^*_
<:x:^~>.^~^^~%_
<:%:*:^:5+:<:9x
<:x:+:+:9!:20''
<:x:^~*:+:+:*__
>:+:#.1x#~#.6#1
<:x:*:*:-:JCHAR2
<:*:*:*:*:+:<:9x
<:x:^~>.%:3 u:EAV
<:x:*:*:3!:0 s:''
<:x:^~>.^^*JCHAR4
<:JCHAR^x:+:JBOXED
<:x:^~>.^^*#dbhelp
<:x:^~>.^^*3 u:DEL
<:x:^~>.^^*#show'show'
<:x:dfh":(>:9)^x:%:#a.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

#### Updates

- Replaced `ab--` with `i+` to achieve -1.

```
b5+:*:*:*:*i+n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59kqm2lBYGZ2nnW//8DAA)

The idea is to factor 16<sup>16</sup> into (((16<sup>2)</sup><sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>, which can be easily computing by duplicating the stack and multiplying `:*`.

### Explanation

```
b5+:*:*:*:*i+n;

b                     Push 11
 5                    Push 5
  +                   Add to make 16
   :*                 Square  ->  16²
     :*:*:*           .. another 3 times to make
                           16¹⁶ = (((16²)²)²)²
           i          Push -1 because no input
            +         16¹⁶ + (-1) = 16¹⁶-1
             n;       Print and Exit
```

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X@lIg5KVFghmaudZ//8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 122 bytes

```
(()())({({})({}[()])}{})({({})({}[()])}{})({({})({}[()])}{})({({})({}[()])}{})({({})({}[()])}{})({({})({}[()])}{})({}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hoamhqalRrVFdCyRrozU0YzVrwWzaiUDY//8DAA)
Also works in Mini-Flak

Comment: You can shorten this. Instead of 2^2^2, you can use 4*2*2 to get 16. `(((()()()()){}){})`. That's 24 Bytes shorter

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 92 Bytes :-D

```
class a{public static void main(String[] a){System.out.print(Long.toUnsignedString(-3/3));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>34</s> 25 bytes (courtesy of l4m2)

```js
(a=BigInt(9+7))**a-a/a+''
```

Works in any console that supports `BigInt`s.

Comment: [27](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFfI9HWKTPdM69Ew1LbXFNTSytRN1FLyyBPW139v@Z/AA)

Comment: [25](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFfI9HWKTPdM69Ew1LbXFNTSytRN1E/UVtd/b/mfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 6 bytes

```
\∑\@Ë;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/5lHHxBiHw93W//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 12 bytes

```
{$`e^$`G-!0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7v1olITVOJcFdV9Gg9n9AUWZeSXRadGzsfwA)

Uses Attache's inbuilt number compression literals. `` $`<string> `` decompresses `<string>` into a number. In this case, `e` maps to `4`, and `G` to `32`. Another solution would be to replace both with `` $`q ``, which maps to `16`. We subtract 1, which can be calculated as `!0`, or \$0!\$. This is a lambda returning the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

## x86_64 machine code (Linux), 7 bytes

```
00000000: 4831 c048 f7d0 c3                        H1.H...
```

Assembly (NASM):

```bash
section .text
global func
func:
xor rax, rax
not rax
ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHBboMwDL3nKyy0Dqgaqk1VD6XtYdqm3XqvuIQQWiqIEQlbqm3fzkIQa7nYcd57znOcMnXuONOw3b4d3mEPS13VSxYxVUEMsk80F2W@Xt0jFIeKYyYitETBzwgJ8YXRopFwhLyVPPjEIgtj394XUkPFChmE3315BLNzjAGtG4vngTcry9ZbmDD@9UcnSrdpxOOEJOTEOdDX484vUZ6gD/7UiLV5L5pYpBJpXQig1XrlumF6ydqqth0nvKf94/OIc6yvQA@QFpI19nSBSNsBJ3x3tgSrGaYAL5Hzl6sWar6BmZpFKpEePARf1jz/p4dwe8n9HRVO@CHMZu4NGPRrGQXwA8ZkN9Fk6rhTgusC5WCQnEpMWel2QPqwIQYbaJhZ9IFI1C43Qnd26d0f)

Comment: `xor rax, rax` => `xor eax, eax` as upper32 is automatically zeroed

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
kḭ²‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwia+G4rcKy4oC5IiwiIiwiIl0=)

2^32 squared, minus one.

Comment: `₆E‹` for -1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$7\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 5.762 bytes

```
{^{3C/@
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJ7XnszQy9AIiwiIl0=)

```
{^{3C/@
  {3    # 3 - 1
 ^      # To the power of
    C/     # The charcode of
      @    # '@' (64)
{       # Decremented
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, <s>64</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```
@set a=@cmd/cset/a
%a%0xafebff0
%a%737095
%a%0xc99f
```

Port of my JavaScript answer. Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 19 bytes

In REPL

```
int('3'*(35-3),7-3)
```

Not in REPL

```
print int('3'*(35-3),7-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
Zw`@t
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Zw%60%40t)

```
 w`   -   64
Z  @  -  set_bit(0, ^)
    t - ^ -1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 18 bytes

```
p (9+7)**(9+7)-7/7
```

Comment: Would `(9+7)**(9+7)` save you a byte?

Answer (score 0):

## MUMPS, 15 bytes

```
w 9+7**(9+7)-'0
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmallTalk – 60 characters

```
Transcript show:(((7+9)raisedTo:(7+9))-(3/3))printString;cr.
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 35 bytes

```
?POW(!.+!.,#X)LOCATE #A,0?ASC("x")
```

`x` should be replaced with `CHR$(1615)`

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 28 Bytes

```
{++(Long.MAX_VALUE​/0.5​)​}​
```

Try it: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5145694419550208

Answer (score 0):

## asm2bf, 9 bytes

Function body assuming `r1 = 0`, returns the desired value in `r1`.

```
decr1
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
GîGpG)+#¡5
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=R%2b5HcEcpKyOhNQ&input=LVE)

```
GîGpG)+#¡5
G              :16
 î             :Slice the following to that length
  GpG          :  16**16
     )         :End slice
      +        :Append
       #¡5     :1615
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 61 bytes

```
[S S S T    S N
_Push_2][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S N
S _Duplicate][T S S N
_Multiply][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgVOBCwg5FYijgOq5gAxOTiD//38A) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation:**

Pretty straight-forward:

1. Push 2
2. Square itself six times
3. Decrease by 1
4. Output as integer

Pushing and outputting the expected integer in one go would be [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNCwMXJpcD5/z8A) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) (Windows only), 14 bytes

```factor
GPTR on-bits .
```

[image]

Only works on Windows (and hence not on TIO/ATO). Not sure whether that's allowed or not.

GPTR is a constant equal to 64 loaded on machines running Windows. `on-bits` takes a value and creates a number with that many on bits.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), 17 bytes (UTF-8)

```
OC"䠎ᴐ᳊╏ɧ
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJPQ1wi5KCO4bSQ4bOK4pWPyaciLCIiXQ==)

Fig doesn't have too much in the way of number builtins, so here is a charcode version. Just get the charcode of each character, then join.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 9 bytes

```c
-Df()0UL-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19fP01D0yDUR/d/Zl6JQm5iZp6GpkI1lwIQFBQBhdI0lFRzSpV0FIDKNK25av//S07LSUwv/q/rAtUIAA)

Tech used before

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
3⁻⁸⁸⁻


3⁻     pushes 3, then decrements
  ⁸    raises to the 8th power
   ⁸   8th power again
    ⁻  decrement
       implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f@FHj7keNO8Bo9///AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 8 bytes

```
"@"XMn;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X4nJQSnCN8/6/38A)

The unprintable is char `0x02`

## Explanation

```
".@"XMn; # whole program
".@"     # 0x02, 64
    X    # e`X`ponentiate
     m   # -1
      n  # output
       ; # terminate execution
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
aeaA,D^nA~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharElMTHXVc4vIc6yACUHGYPAA)

No numbers at all!

##### Explanation

```python
aeaA,D^nA~  #                           STACK:
ae          # Constant for 160          160
  aA        # Constant for 10           160, 10
    ,       # Integer divide            16
     D^     # To the power of itself    18446744073709551616
       n    # Negate                    -18446744073709551616
        A~  # Bitwise not               18446744073709551615
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
VuJv
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VuJv&i=)

Unpacked and packed it's 4 bytes

## Explanation

```
Vu   # 2**32
  J  # squared
   v # -1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 27 bytes

```bash
!
<<<$?$[35#ULOSOKRBNKG]$?5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7FblsbGxU7FWijU2VQ338g_29g5z8vN1jVexNISqgCmEaAA)

Zsh only allows signed 64 bit integers, so we need a string method. Notice that `ULOSOKRBNKG` is `84467440737095516` in base 35, and contains no disallowed characters. Then we just need to attach two `1`s and a `5`: 5 is an allowed digit anyway, and we can get 1 by running a command that fails (in this case `!`) and taking its exit status in `$?`.

Answer (score -1):

## Python, 20 (or 26) bytes

```
(5-3)**ord('@')-3**0
```

`ord('@')` is equal to 64.

The full function/programme (@BusinessCat, I hope this is more in line with what is expected) would add 6 bytes:

```
print (5-3)**ord('@')-3**0
```

The 26 byte version would work if we wanted to pipe the output:

```
python -c "print (5-3)**ord('@')-3**0"
```

The 20 byte version would not.

Comment: This is a snippet, every submission needs to be a full program or function.

Comment: you can do `3/3` instead of `3**0` and you can remove the space after `print` to save 2 bytes